# SharePoint 2013 Distributed Cache "cacheHostInfo is null" with "Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance"

Tags: powershell, 2013, service

I am attempting to remove a server as a cache host in my SharePoint 2013 environment.

Currently the service shows as Stopped on the server that I am attempting to remove from the cache cluster.  I also am getting a warning in Central Administration stating:

> This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability problems.
>
> This Distributed Cache service on this Distributed Cache host has been stopped but not unregistered from the farm. In order to avoid reliability issues, it is recommended that a Distributed Cache host with a stopped Distributed Cache service be unregistered from the farm.

I run the command from PowerShell:

> Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance

It errors out saying:

> cacheHostInfo is null

Looking in the ULS logs I see this:

> A failure occurred in SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance::UnprovisionInternal. cacheHostInfo is null for host 'server_name'.

When I open the AppFabric Server Configuration Wizard on the server it states:

> This machine is not a member of an AppFabric Caching cluster.

I'm looking mainly to remove the service from that server since I have no plans of running the Distributed Cache on there anyways but I can't find my way around this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Using SharePoint Powershell

```
$SPFarm = Get-SPFarm
$cacheClusterName = "SPDistributedCacheCluster_" + $SPFarm.Id.ToString() 
$cacheClusterManager = [Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.Utilities.SPDistributedCacheClusterInfoManager]::Local 
$cacheClusterInfo = $cacheClusterManager.GetSPDistributedCacheClusterInfo($cacheClusterName); 
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.Service.Tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.Server.Name) -eq $env:computername}  
$serviceInstance.Delete()
```

You may have to issue the Delete command a couple of times.